# Joomla 2.5 - where to change registration mail sending, user confirmation email is sent to admin email, not to user

Tags: email, joomla, registration, send

Joomla 2.5 with Virtuemart 2.0.18. When the user try to register with the new "user email" to Joomla, the confirmation email has been sent. But user confirmation email has been send to "admin email" not to "user email". Then order confirmation email in virtuemart is sent correctly to "user email". Do you think it can be caused of Joomla or it can cause mail server ? Which .php files to check the sending files  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. update was absolutely unsuccesful, because of uncompatibility of template and also older version Joomla. My sollution is at the moment to make clean Joomla 3 installation and make new joomla 3 compatible template. It takes sometime but will be for me faster then trying to update everything. The I set "php mail" in Global Configuration of joomla and thatt's it.